# How to find the mode across rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in r which contains information about clients purchasing history of the last year the data frame looks something like this:

```
Client | Prod A | Prod B | Prod C
---------------------------------
  A    |   1    |    0   |   1
  B    |   1    |    1   |   0
  C    |   1    |    0   |   1 
  D    |   0    |    0   |   1
  E    |   1    |    0   |   0
---------------------------------
```

Where 1 means the client has purchased the product at some point and 0 it hasnt bought it at all.

In this particular table the most frequent combination is Product A and Product C with 2 cases out of 5.
I want to find a method/function that will get me the most common combination of products for a data frame of this type of any dimensions.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you want to know the combination of only length 2 or it could be of any length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
res <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~., data=dat[,-1]))
res
#   Prod.A Prod.B Prod.C Freq
# 1      0      0      0    0
# 2      1      0      0    1
# 3      0      1      0    0
# 4      1      1      0    1
# 5      0      0      1    1
# 6      1      0      1    2
# 7      0      1      1    0
# 8      1      1      1    0
```

From this you can see the counts of combinations, the "max" of which is

```r
subset(res, Freq == max(Freq))
#   Prod.A Prod.B Prod.C Freq
# 6      1      0      1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe in `df`

```
aggregate(Client~Prod.A+Prod.B+Prod.C,df,length)

  Prod.A Prod.B Prod.C Client
1      1      0      0      1
2      1      1      0      1
3      0      0      1      1
4      1      0      1      2
```

the last column Client giving the count

Answer (score 1):

Solution using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Client = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                 `Prod A` = c(1,1,1,0,1),
                 `Prod B` = c(0,1,0,0,0),
                 `Prod C` = c(1,0,1,1,0))

df %>%
     dplyr::group_by(Prod.A,Prod.B,Prod.C) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(count = n())
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Prod.A, Prod.B [3]
  Prod.A Prod.B Prod.C count
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1      0      0      1     1
2      1      0      0     1
3      1      0      1     2
4      1      1      0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Client = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                 `Prod A` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                 `Prod B` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                 `Prod C` = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(length = sum(Prod.A, Prod.B, Prod.C)) %>%
  group_by(Prod.A, Prod.B, Prod.C) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(count == max(count) & length > 1) %>%
  select(1:4)
```

which will produce:

```
  Client Prod.A Prod.B Prod.C
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A           1      0      1
2 C           1      0      1
```